# List comprehension += operator

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

How to convert this for loop:

```
smoke_ray = [18, 14]
total = 0 
for i in smoke_ray: 
    total += i
```

Into a list comprehension? I tried:

```
smoke_ray = [18, 14]
total = 0 
[total += i for i in smoke_ray]
```

Is the problem the `+=` operator?
that’s where I get an error

Updated with full code:

```
days = [
    { "day_name": "wed",
      "smoked_at": {
        '15:30': 1,
        '16:30': 1,
        '16:50': 2,
        '17:30': 1,
        '18:30': 1,
        '20:20': 1,
        '21:30': 1,
        '22:30': 1,
        '25:00': 5
        }
    },
    { "day_name": "thurs",
        "smoked_at": {
        '08:15': 1,
        '08:40': 1,
        '09:20': 1,
        '10:00': 1,
        '11:20': 1,
        '11:38': 1, 
        '12:10': 1,
        '13:00': 1,
        '14:26': 1,
        '15:40': 1, 
        '17:08': 1,
        '18:10': 1,
        '19:30': 1,
        '20:20': 1,
        '22:00': 1,
        '23:00': 1,
        '25:00': 2
        }
    }
]

smoke_ray = []

for i in days:
    print(i["day_name"])
    smokes = i["smoked_at"].values()
    smokes_day = sum(smokes)
    print(smokes_day)
    smoke_ray.append(i)

total = 0 
for i in smoke_ray: 
    total += i 
print(total)
```

When trying to convert the last for loop to a list comprehension (are you telling me it’s not a shorthand way of writing a loop? I heard it was faster)

I get this error:

```
File "compiler.py", line 47
    [total += i for i in smoke_ray]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When trying to use sum, it just won’t work:
`sum(smoke_ray)`

```
wed
14
thurs
18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compiler.py", line 47, in 
    sum(smoke_ray)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict'
```

Comment: List comprehension expression is supposed to return a list. What kind of list do you expect this to return?

Comment: Use just `sum(smoke_ray) `

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Inappropriate usage aside, the first part of a list comprehension must be an *expression*. `+=`, however, is not an operator and cannot be part of an expression. It's part of the syntax for an augmented assignment *statement*.

Comment: If I try what you suggested@toRex which I’ve tried before I get this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict'`

Comment: @chepner am I better off using a lambda function loop? I tried that and just can’t get the hang of it

Comment: What do you mean by "lambda function loop"?

Comment: @chepner I’m sick of using for loops, I thought I might be able to use a recursive lambda function to do the for loop instead but I’m just stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you've now added for context, I think the issue you're having isn't actually in summing the list, it's in constructing the list itself. When I run your original code, with the for loop, that also fails for me.

I think the problem is in the line `smoke_ray.append(i)`: Here, you're appending an entire element of the dictionary (e.g: `{ "day_name": "...", "smoked_at": { ... } }`) to the `smoke_ray` list. Then, it doesn't make sense to sum over values in that list, since they're dictionaries. If you wanted to add each `smokes_day` to the list, and then sum over those, you'd do `smoke_ray.append(smoke_day)` within that loop. Then, you should be able to just use `sum` as mentioned in other answers to sum over the list.

Edit: This isn't to say that there aren't more improvements that could be done to the code btw, a simple change that would preserve the original structure would be to change your for loop to be something like this:

```py
total = 0
for i in days:
    print(i['day_name'])
    smokes = i['smoked_at'].values()
    smokes_day = sum(smokes)
    print(smokes_day)
    total += smokes_day

print(total)
```

That way you can sum the values like you want within one loop, without the need to construct another list/use a list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you and for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a list comprehension.  Just use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
total = sum(smoke_ray)
```

Comment: See full code and error when trying to use `sum`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the sum value list wise then you can use

```
import itertools
smoke_ray = [18, 14]
print(list(itertools.accumulate(smoke_ray)))
```

This will show you the sum of the series by element

Output

```
[18, 32]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is specifically an operation to transform an input list into an output list via two actions:

- *transformation* of each element (also known as “mapping”)
- *filtering* based on some filtering criterion

That’s it.

The operation you want is fundamentally different: you want to *accumulate* the elements in a list using a given operation. This action is also known as a “reduction” and is available in the Python library via `functools.reduce`.

So you could write

```
import functools
import operator

functools.reduce(operator.add, smoke_ray)
```

… but this is such a common operation that there’s a shorthand for it: as mentioned, you can also just use `sum(smoke_ray)`.

Comment: See full code I’m losing my mind over why `sum`isn’t working

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways, since you asking here for `list comprehension` (although list comprehension is a bad option here, a battery option is `sum(your_list)` ) try this:

```
sum([i for i in [18, 14]])
```

```
24
```